# Credit card form html values length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, credit-card

I tried a lot of examples and still can't find a good way to solve my issue.

If I use a text field, then my app crops the last 3 digits and make transaction impossible. The problem is because the user might input `space`,

for example -

```
1234 1234 4564 1
```

When I use JQuery on (type="text"), I filter the characters, but I still have problem with space and cropping.

Any idea how to go about this in a better way?

I am not really  fan of key mapping with JS Because I don't know how user want to use the space.

Here is my code -

```
<input class="required" id="field" type="number" min="0000" max="9999" pattern="[0-9]{4}"  size="4" name="cvv"/>

<div class="FormInput">
                    <input name="var_creditcard_no" type="number" id="var_creditcard_no" onkeypress="return Check_mobile_number(event)" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo set_value('var_creditcard_no', '') ?>" placeholder="Credit Card Number *">
                    <?php echo form_error('var_creditcard_no', '<label class="error">', '</label>') ?>
                </div>
```

This is the JQuery code -

```
    $(function() {
      var txt = $("#myTextbox");
      var func = function() {
        txt.val(txt.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
      }
      txt.keyup(func).blur(func);
    });
```

Comment: `.on('input', func)` is your solution.

Comment: @thenchanter its not illegal form witch send data to payment gateway. its talk about validation problem cus user input directly change state of transaction.

Comment: It's illegal to store credit card information, at least in my country. Why not use the payment gateway directly? Before sending the data you're storing it in your server, and if somehow your server gets hacked and your customer's credit card information stolen, you will go to jail (in any developed country of the world).

Comment: Are you open to using plugins? if yes,maybe check this [link]http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Easy-Credit-Card-Inputs-Creditly-js.html

Comment: @thenchanter PCI says storing pan last 4 number is ok with them u cant store Cvv and exp date and personal information. i store only last 4 digits of c card number so its easier to do re found and verify user. And this form is directly sent to payment gateway Only cc number is used for invoicing propose. but no worry its not pci problem here its about html 5 mistakes

Answer (score 1):

HTML code

```
cc number
<br/>
<input class="required" id="field" type="text" maxlength="16" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="cc" />max 16
<br/>cvv
<br/>
<input class="required" id="field" type="text" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="cvv" />max 4
```

Js code

```
/* isNumberKey
    Only allows NUMBERS to be keyed into a text field.
    @environment ALL
    @param evt - The specified EVENT that happens on the element.
    @return True if number, false otherwise.
 Source:
 http://www.kk-design.com/DevCookbook/JavascriptLibrary/isnumberkey.html
*/
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    // Added to allow decimal, period, or delete
    if (charCode == 110 || charCode == 190 || charCode == 46) return true;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) return false;
    return true;
} // isNumberKey
```

[Solution is here](https://jsfiddle.net/aleksa1302/0prkp5r4/) i don't like it personally but its work.

But probably they should put new  html type for credit card i think that all will use it .

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = '1234 1234 4564 1';
txt = txt.replace(/\s/g,'');
var valid = txt.match(/([0-9]{16})/g);
if(valid){
     //submit form
}
```

### **NOTICE**

Storing credit card **information** is not against the law; However, it is highly advised not to do so because you can be held accountable for any damages that happen.

First Things first, become PCI compliant https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf

Once you become PCI compliant it is important to understand what information you can **not** record in your system:

- Full track data (magnetic-stripe data or equivalent on a chip)
- CAV2/CVC2/CVV2/CID
- PINs/PIN blocks

According to the official PCI compliance documentation the following information is not considered secure:

- Primary Account Number (PAN)
- Card holder name
- Expiration date
- Service code

> "The primary account number is the defining factor for cardholder data.
>   If cardholder name, service code, and/or expiration date are stored,
>   processed or transmitted with the PAN, or are otherwise present in the
>   cardholder data environment, they must be protected in accordance with
>   applicable PCI DSS requirements"
>
> PCI DSS Requirements 3.3 and 3.4 apply only to PAN. If PAN is stored
>   with other elements of cardholder data, only the PAN must be rendered
>   unreadable according to PCI DSS Requirement 3.4.

Comment: PCI part perfect , but js which u provided not fixing problem its going to rewrite space but not going to fix problem with missed number after maxlenght=16

Comment: Well the only thing you can do is return false and not submit the form i guess i can write in if length < 16

Comment: agree:) but i will stick on return which going to finish work .

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 patterns to achieve this.

Amex:

```
[0-9]{4} *[0-9]{6} *[0-9]{5}
```

Credit Card

```
[0-9]{13,16}
```

Diners Club

```
^([30|36|38]{2})([0-9]{12})$
```

Just use it like this,

```
pattern="[0-9]{13,16}"
```

Comment: i try it on fiddle and  not doing well